# Django: FILES Form Not Validating

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a basic Form that accepts a file / image from a template. For some reason it won't validate and I can't see the error.

***views.py***

```
# Flag a Job as complete
@login_required()
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='Developer').exists(), login_url='/login/', redirect_field_name='not allowed')
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def job_complete(request, jobid, userid):

    # Get the Job
    job = Jobs.objects.get(id=jobid)

    jobsubmit = JobSubmitForm(request.FILES)
    if jobsubmit.is_valid():
        js = jobsubmit.save(commit=False)
        js.user_id = userid
        js.job_id = jobid
        js.save()
        job.status = 'IR'
        job.save()
        return redirect('view_job', jobid=jobid, slug=job.slug)
    else:
        messages.error(request, "There are form errors!")
        return redirect('view_job', jobid=jobid, slug=job.slug)
```

***forms.py***

```
class JobSubmitForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = JobSubmit
        fields = ('file', 'image', 'comment', 'gitHubLink')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        jobsubmit = super(JobSubmitForm, self).save(commit=False)
        jobsubmit.user_id = self.cleaned_data['user_id']
        jobsubmit.job_id = self.cleaned_data['job_id']

        if commit:
            jobsubmit.save()
        return jobsubmit
```

***view.html***

```
    <form method="post" action="/job/job_complete/j{{ job.id }}/u{{ request.user.id }}/" class="form-inline btn-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="span6 inline">
        <label class="control-label">Attach Files: </label>{{ job_submit.file }}
        <p class="help-block">Attach files that go with this Job.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6 inline">
        <label class="control-label">Attach Images: </label>{{ job_submit.image }}
        <p class="help-block">Attach images that go with this Job.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6 inline">
        <label class="control-label">GitHub URL: </label>{{ job_submit.gitHubLink|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Example: https://www.github.com/path/to/code/repo/or/commit" }}
        <p class="help-block">If hosting work on GitHub.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6 inline"><label class="control-label">Job Comments(Required): </label>{{ job_submit.comment|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Example: Fun Job! Please keep me in mind for future work!" }} </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-med pull-left"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Job Complete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

***models.py***

```
# Store data related to a Job (files, comments, etc.)
class JobSubmit(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Jobs)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/jobs/files", blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/jobs/images", blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    gitHubLink = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

Hopefully it's not something silly... it's been a long day and sleepy programming isn't the best idea. :/

Appreciate the help if anyone sees what's wrong. Pointers welcomed, as well. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
jobsubmit = JobSubmitForm(request.FILES)
```

should be as:

```
jobsubmit = JobSubmitForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

try it?

Comment: Sigh. Yep that was it. I should go to sleep before making any more dumb mistakes. Haha. Cheers, Greg.

Comment: Plus you should actually return the invalid form to the template so the user can see the errors generated.